# Why does MainActivity pops up before FirebaseUi gets displayed

Tags: java, firebase, android-activity, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have built a small chat app using firebase. I have also implemented firebaseui for logging in. The problem I am facing is, if the user has not signed up. Whenever the app launches it should take me directly to FirebaseUi signup options but what is happening with current code is for a **milli second** it shows the layout of main activity and then goes to FirebaseUi.

Also when I am pressing back button before exiting it again shows me the layout of main activity. I want the activity to get destroyed and take me to home (android) but it shows me main activity for a millisecond and then the app exits.

Why is this happening?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private TextView mUserNameTextView;
    private Button mSignOutButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mUserNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name_text_view);
        mSignOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    mUserNameTextView.setText(user.getDisplayName());

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };


        mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signOut();
            }
        });
    }

    private void signOut() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        mUserNameTextView.setText("");
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {

            // when app is paused remove the state listener
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // adding the state listener
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you finishing the FirebaseUI activity?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at this. I only have main activity ( and I did not create login activity java file)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you won't be able to make the Main Activity not display for a millisecond upon app start, since you are first opening the Main Activity and then you redirect it (if I understood correctly).

I can however help you with your problem when you press the back button.

Add this to your FirebaseUi code as a normal method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class); 
//replace "CurrentActivity" and "NextActivity" with your activity names
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will open the activity you want when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks but I have only one activity (main activity) inside it I have written a code for firebase UI (I heard firebaseUi has its own activity) so yes why main activity shows up even when user is not logged in, it should directly show me firebaseui sign up options

Answer (score 0):

When you start new activity after logged in using FirebaseUI then you need to finish(will remove the activity from backstack) the Login Activity when you start activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, NextActivity.class); 
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Comment: Thanks but I have only one activity (main activity) inside it I have written a code for firebase UI (I heard firebaseUi has its own activity) so yes why main activity shows up even when user is not logged in, it should directly show me firebaseui sign up options